# Wizard component not working after PrimeFaces update from 3.4 to 3.4.2

Tags: primefaces, upgrade, wizard

I have recently upgraded **PrimeFaces** from **3.4** to **3.4.2** because of performance bug in **PickList** component. After this upgrade my **Wizard** components have stopped to function.

I'm using custom buttons for navigations, using `widgetVar`, `next()` and `prev()` as defined by users guide 3.4.

```
<p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" flowListener="#{wizard.onFlowProcess}"
            showStepStatus="false" showNavBar="false">

<p:commandButton value="Weiter" onclick="wiz.next()" update="dialogRespHeader">
```

This was working in version 3.4. After update after clicking on the button, the *waitprogress* animation is displayed and nothing more happens, no matter how long I wait. There is no hanging request to server: the request is sent immediately after clicking the button and the response comes also after the moment. It looks correct:

```
<partial-response>
<changes>
<update id="mainForm:j_id1831660928_7d431f69"> [some content]
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"currentStep":"internUserTab"}</extension>
<extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"currentStep":"internUserTab"}</extension>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

So the question is: What have changed between this versions? Is this a bug, or maybe the API change (I can't find any info about api changes for this component).

**update** 
FireBug console shows error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data
```

Can it be an error in jQuery 1.8.2? This is the greatest and the most dangerous change between those versions.

Comment: I'm curious about this as well since I can't get the wizard to work. Firebug reports ... Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **bug** in PrimeFaces with **caching** resources by browser.

The version of jQuery has changed, but the name of the resource was left unchanged, therefore browser will load old version of jQuery from cache, **until you clear your cache**.

Replicated multiple time with migration from 3.4 to 3.5. Happened in all cases with various components, the only way to get rid of it is to send info to all users with instructions to clean the browser cache.